# Keep front-end state with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, local-storage

I have a Rails app and I would like to save the state of my divs if a user is logged in.

Exemple: someone is logged in and clicks on a div to hide it. I would like that to be stored somewhere so if he opens the page again, this div will still be hidden.

I don't want to use local storage, because I want the state to be saved if I go on a mobile or another computer/browser too. It needs to be the same everywhere, depending on the user.

I was thinking about storing each state of each div as boolean in my user model, but this idea does not sound clean at all and I don't think I'll be able to sleep at night if I do this

Any idea?
I think React/Redux would handle that easily (maybe not and it's just local too?) but at the moment I am stuck with Rails..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Redux memory is not persistent, they use cookie or localStorage to save data.

You can use a different user model (like "user metadata" or "user customization") and retrieve the information when needed

Comment: Ok, good to know. The only difference I see with Redux is that JS is asynchronous, whereas Ruby is not. So if I implement this and have 100.000 users clicking on divs it might become SUPER slow, no?

Comment: Yeah it could be slow, because they are 100.000 actions sent to backend. 
That's why usually you have a localStorage or cookie to save this informations

Comment: Yes, JS would still be quicker because it would not wait one by one :/ Thanks, I'll think about it

Comment: @Jessicascn I post an answer since I had many ideas I couldn't add them here without a description. Regarding your 100K users clicking on divs concern, you'll probably need to have that async and is fairly easy to have it for Rails as well. No need for React.

Answer (score 2):

React/Redux will not save you since nothing magical happens there except for some convenient binding. Behind the curtains they use the same "browser features".

I'm afraid you need to find the best trade-off for you. I'll post some ideas:

#### Stick to localStorage

Probably not need to say much here since you investigated this.

#### Bound to Chrome

Since Chrome 25, they gave access to [storage.sync](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) and you can develop your system around this. Always try to retrieve data, if there is any and then remember to persist new data and sync it. Maybe other browsers support this, but the downside is you'll have to have the code for those as well.

#### Experiment with webRTC

You can transfer data between two browsers using webRTC. While I don't have many experience with this, I can't recommend it, but it's definetly an approach you'd like to consider.

Maybe check this project: https://github.com/cjb/serverless-webrtc

#### Create your own storage

Pick up a storage (I think even firebase/dynamodb will work) and build a system to save user preferences. If you have Auth0, you can keep some logic in there and since they are offering SSO, it will be fairly easy to check for those customizations.

Remember, since you don't want to use localStorage, you'll need to keep sessions and save this preference under a user_id or something.

In my opinion, there is no best solution for this but only what you want to trade in order to support this. If you don't mind keeping the whole business logic, I don't see why creating a storage for this will make it too slow. Measure the load and optimize along the way.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for this, I'll have a look! When you say in your comment "you need to have async", how do you implement that with Rails ? I did not even know that was possible, this is great!

Comment: Depending on the level of experience, there are multiple options. I think the easiest is to make some JS calls to controller actions and enqueue jobs using ActiveJob to persist the changes. A more advanced alternative is something like concurrent-ruby gem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a user preferences type of configuration.  As such, you can probably just store the settings as single field in your User modal.  For that you could use either a serializable hash or json type.

So assuming you have a `app/models/user.rb`

Add an run migration

```
rails g migration add_view_options_to_users view_options:text
rake db:migrate
```

Add this to your model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :view_options, Hash
end
```

Then in your users controller you can post to your update action so you'll want to add a field to `permitted_params`

```
private

def permitted_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:view_options, #other options etc.)
end
```

From here you'll need to write some javascript to post view_options to users/update or custom route if you prefer. But basically each field's value will be saved inside a controller action so something like:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  opts = @user.view_options || {}
  user.view_options = opts.merge(params[:view_options])
  if @user.save
    render json: { status: true, user_id: @user.id }
  else
    render json: { status: false, errors: @user.errors.full_messages }
  end
end
```